# values from table that not exist in another (by seperate group column)

Tags: oracle, join

This qes is about oracle db.

I have a table (T1) with several columns:

| group | id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 50 |
| A | 5 | 40 |
| B | 4 | 54 |
| C | 1 | 33 |
| C | 6 | 33 |
| D | 5 | 13 |
| D | 3 | 4 |

And another table (T2) with 2 columns:

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 2 | bbb |
| 3 | ccc |
| 4 | ddd |
| 5 | eee |
| 6 | fff |
| 7 | ggg |

The Id in this table (t2) is unique.
the connection between the two tables is by the "id" column.

I need to check for each (!) Group in T1 (A, B, C, D),
which of the "id" from T2 - not found for this group in T1,
and the result needs to be: group + id (that does not exist in this group)

for the example on the above tables, I expected to get this result:

| group | id |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 6 |
| A | 7 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 7 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 4 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 7 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 4 |
| D | 6 |
| D | 7 |

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to create all possible record combinations by using a Cartesian join and then match all groups and select non existing via `left join` and `not null`

```
create table T1 (c1 varchar2(10), c2 number(10), c3 number(10))

 insert into T1 values('A',     1,  50);
 insert into T1 values('A',     5,  40);
 insert into T1 values('B',     4 , 54);
 insert into T1 values('C',     1,  33);
 insert into T1 values('C', 6,  33);
 insert into T1 values('D',     5,  13);
 insert into T1 values('D',     3,  4);

create table T2 (c6 number(10), c7 varchar2(10))

 insert into T2 values( 1,  'aaa');
 insert into T2 values( 2,  'bbb');
 insert into T2 values( 3,  'ccc');
 insert into T2 values( 4,  'ddd');
 insert into T2 values( 5,  'eee');
 insert into T2 values( 6,  'fff');
 insert into T2 values( 7,  'ggg');

 SELECT tx.c1, tx.c6, ty.c1
 FROM
     (select c1, c6 
      from 
          (select distinct c1 from T1) ta,
          (select distinct c6 from T2) tb) tx -- tx is the cartisian product
          left join 
          (select c1, c2 from T1 group by c1, c2) ty 
              on tx.c1 = ty.c1 and tx.c6 = ty.c2
WHERE 
    ty.c1 is null
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

This gets you exactly what you're looking for.
Tested and verified

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you may use [partitioned join](https://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/270646.htm)

> ```
> with a(grp, id, price) as (
>   select 'A', 1, 50 from dual union all
>   select 'A', 5, 40 from dual union all
>   select 'B', 4, 54 from dual union all
>   select 'C', 1, 33 from dual union all
>   select 'C', 6, 33 from dual union all
>   select 'D', 5, 13 from dual union all
>   select 'D', 3, 4 from dual
> )
> , b (id, descr) as (
>   select 1, 'aaa' from dual union all
>   select 2, 'bbb' from dual union all
>   select 3, 'ccc' from dual union all
>   select 4, 'ddd' from dual union all
>   select 5, 'eee' from dual union all
>   select 6, 'fff' from dual union all
>   select 7, 'ggg' from dual
> )
> select
>   grp
>   , id
> from a
>   partition by (grp)
>   right join b
>     using (id)
> where a.price is null
> order by grp, id
> ```
>
> ```
> GRP | ID
> :-- | -:
> A   |  2
> A   |  3
> A   |  4
> A   |  6
> A   |  7
> B   |  1
> B   |  2
> B   |  3
> B   |  5
> B   |  6
> B   |  7
> C   |  2
> C   |  3
> C   |  4
> C   |  5
> C   |  7
> D   |  1
> D   |  2
> D   |  4
> D   |  6
> D   |  7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9643c90ee92147932ceeecb1c9ab589d)*

Answer (score 1):

First, find all the possible combinations, then determine which of them don't exist:

```
WITH cteCombinations
 AS (SELECT DISTINCT T1."group", T2.ID
       FROM T1
       CROSS JOIN T2)
SELECT c."group", c.ID
  FROM cteCombinations c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T1
    ON T1.ID = c.ID AND
       T1."group" = c."group"
  WHERE T1.ID IS NULL
  ORDER BY c."group", c.ID
```

The CTE (Common Table Expression) uses a CROSS JOIN to find all of the unique combinations of group and ID; then the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is used to determine which of the combinations don't exist in T1.

Another way to do it is:

```
WITH cteCombinations
 AS (SELECT DISTINCT T1."group", T2.ID
       FROM T1
       CROSS JOIN T2)
SELECT c."group", c.ID
  FROM cteCombinations c
  WHERE (c."group", c.ID) NOT IN (SELECT "group", ID
                                    FROM T1)
  ORDER BY c."group", c.ID
```

Here we use the same CTE to generate the possible combinations, but instead of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` we use a `NOT IN` comparison to determine which of the combinations are not present in table T1.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f824971c32ea0ce997b1d290a149376c)

Comment: excellent solution! Thank you!!!